# Ingress nginx Unable to rotate token: failed to read token file "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token"

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am running nginx-ingress `v0.44.0`  on Kubernetes version `v1.20.2`, install ingress using helm chat `ingress-nginx-3.23.0`. nginx taking the traffic from the log file I see this error message.

```
E0209 23:21:41.300842       6 token_source.go:152] Unable to rotate token: failed to read token file "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token": open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: permission denied
E0209 23:21:41.316286       6 token_source.go:152] Unable to rotate token: failed to read token file "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token": open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: permission denied
```

Nignx is running uid `101` but `serviceaccount` directory owned by `root` user.

How to fix this error message?

Thanks

Comment: @ It might be also a RBAC issue.. Did you checked you ve proper RBAC for this service account?

Comment: @semural RBAC rule created by helm chat automatically. I have to make  runas uid to `0`. now error is gone

Comment: Can you post is as an answer to be more visible for community ?

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda odd, as I've tested I haven't experienced such a error.

You could use [`securityContext`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/), set

- fsGroup: 101 or
- runAsUser/runAsGroup

But still the ingress-nginx sets appropriate `securityContext` (for example to bind on 80/443), so it should work.

Comment: helm alreay set the `secuirtyContext`.  here the info `securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          capabilities:
            add:
            - NET_BIND_SERVICE
            drop:
            - ALL
          runAsUser: 101
`

Answer (score 0):

As @sfgroups mentioned solution is to make nignx not running uid `101` but `0`.
Add flag to installation command:  `--set controller.image.runAsUser=0`.

Read: [helm-nginx-ingress-installation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/).